# Hibernate, EHCache, Read-Write cache, adding item to a list

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, seam

I have an entity that has a collection in it.  The collection is a OneToMany unidirectional relationship storing who viewed a particular file.  The problem I am having is that after I load the entity and try to update the collection, I don't get any errors, but the collection is never updated:

Entity:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable
protected List<User> users;
```

File Servlet

```
@In
private EntityQuery<File> File_findById;

...

File file = File_findById(fileId);
file.getUsers().add(user);
session.update(file);
```

Even though I call `session.update(file)` and I see stuff in hibernate logs, I don't see anything in the database indicating that it was saved.

Walter

Comment: Do you use container managed persistence or manual transactions? In the latter case, do you commit the transaction properly?

Comment: Are transactions automatically handled here? Where is the cache stuff? Does it work without it?

Comment: Yeah, it automatically handles transactions.  I disabled the cache and have the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **property access** instead of field access because of it enables **Automatic dirty checking** by Hibernate and use @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE) instead

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return this.users;
}
```

regards,

Answer (score 1):

Why do you cascade the persist (create) operation only if you also want to cascade merge  / update?

With EJB3 / JPA annotations, you may want to add another [cascading](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association-cascade) type:

- `CascadeType.MERGE`

Or maybe even:

- `CascadeType.ALL` (which also covers Hibernate specific operations like save-update, lock)

If you want to use Hibernate extensions, you may want to use the [`@Cascade`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-cascade) annotation to cascade:

- `SAVE_UPDATE`